# Limit of Distance on Stereographically Projected Sphere for $K\to 0$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spherical-geometry

Let $S_K^n$ be the stereographically projected sphere (on the Euclidean plane $E^n$). Where $n$ is the dimensionality of the sphere and $K$ is its sectional cruvature. Then the distance function for $x,y\in S_K^n$ is:
$$
d_K(x,y)=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}
\arccos\left(
\frac{
4\langle x,y\rangle
+
(||Kx||_2^2-1)(||Ky||_2^2-1)
}{
(||Kx||_2^2+1)(||Ky||_2^2+1)
}
\right)
$$
Prove or disprove that in the limit we have:
$$
\lim_{K\to 0}d_K(x,y)
=c||x-y||_2,
\tag{*}
$$
where $c$ is a constant factor (most likely $2$).

This would mean that in the limit we recover Euclidean-like geometry.

Note that the distance function above results from the stereographic projection of the sphere through the north pole: $S_K^n\setminus\{\text{north pole}\}\to E^n$.

---

I'm not sure that this can be shown. However, for the Poincaré disk (if $d_K$ was the distance on the Poincaré disk and $x,y$ would be on the disk) one can show that the upper relationship $(*)$ holds with $c=2$.

One might have to add that $x$ and $y$ lie in the southern hemisphere for such a relationship to hold.

Comment: As far as I can tell, taking the limit of $d_K$ using l'Hospital several times, combined with the fact that $2<x,y> = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 - ||x-y||^2$ should yield something similar to the desired limit, potentially with a constant factor, and potentially with the desired distance squared. The computation is fairly messy and I might have potentially made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: You should give some additional explanations. I guess you consider the stereographic projection $s : S^2 \setminus \{ north pole \} \to \mathbb R^2$. Then $d_K(x,y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb R^2$ is defined as $\lVert s^{-1}(x) - s^{-1}(y) \rVert$ with Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^3$? What is the role of the parameter $K$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, i consider the stereographic projection in $n$ dimensions. $K$ is the sectional curvature of the sphere. I've added everything to the question now.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you have written for $d_K(x,y)$ does not posses a finite limit as $K\to 0$ for most choices of $x$ and $y$. Indeed,
$$
\cos\Bigl[\sqrt{K}\cdot d_K(x,y)\Bigr]=\frac{
4\langle x,y\rangle
+
(||Kx||_2^2-1)(||Ky||_2^2-1)
}{
(||Kx||_2^2+1)(||Ky||_2^2+1)
}
.
$$
Since $\cos$ is continuous and
$$
\lim_{K\to 0}\frac{
4\langle x,y\rangle
+
(||Kx||_2^2-1)(||Ky||_2^2-1)
}{
(||Kx||_2^2+1)(||Ky||_2^2+1)
}=1+4\langle x,y\rangle,
$$
it follows that $\sqrt{K}\cdot d_K(x,y)$ converges to a non-zero constant as $K\to 0$, for suitable $x,y$.
But since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\to\infty$ as $K\to 0$, this means that $$d_k(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\cdot \sqrt{K}\cdot d_K(x,y)$$
also tends to $\infty$ as $K\to 0$.

Thus, there does not exist any finite $c$ with the property that $\lim_{K\to 0}d_K(x,y)
=c||x-y||_2,$ since the left side is infinite for most $x,y$ whereas the right side is always finite.